# Spring : How to manually reset connection pool's connection?

Tags: database, spring, connection-pooling

I am trying to validate the database health manually using @Aspect.
And if something happened in DatabaseA (in my case is DatabaseA have no more write permission) the application will switch to DatabaseB.
How can I manually re-initialize the connection pool so that I can ensure all connection is going to DatabaseB?

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(value=1)
public class PostServiceAspect extends BaseService {

    @Before("execution(* com.some.class.execute(..))")
    public void databaseHealthCheck() {
        try {
            databaseDao.excuteHealthCheckSQL(); // execute "UPDATE table SET field = 1;"
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            databaseDao.switchTargetDatabase(); // switch to databaseB
            // How to re-initialize the connection pool
        }
    }

//DataSource config
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://testinghost:3306/devgpayment" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    <property name="maxTotal" value="40" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="40" />
    <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="10000" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="5000" />
</bean>
```

Comment: That depends on the connection pool implementation used - we can't see that in the question. If it doesn't allow a "shutdown-reconfigure-start", you could make a proxy that shuts the old pool down, discards it, creates a new one and starts it and then redirects the requests to the new one.

Comment: As the connection pool is handled by spring (with the mysql driver), so I did not implement anythings related to the connection pool. May you also provide me more information on how to "make a proxy" for shutting down the old pool too?